# cakephp echo count

Tags: cakephp

Hi I have a like button which updates the likes table field type with like. I want to count the number of likes in the table, in my controller I have this,

// Load Likes Model and retrive number of likes and dislikes

```
    $this->loadModel('Like');

    $related_likes = $this->Like->find('count', array(
        'conditions' => array('uploadid' => $id)
    ));
    $this->set('likes', $related_likes);
    }
```

How do I go about echoing the number of likes in my view??

Would really appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `set()`, the name you define becomes a variable in the view.

In your view:

```
echo $likes;
```